# Make Installer for Both 64 and 32 bit

Tags: c#, wix, installation, 32bit-64bit, wix3.5

I use `WIX` to create an MSI installer for a DLL.

I would like to make one installer that allows to install the program on 64 bit platform just as on 32 bit.

The registry entries I have to define, are different for 32 and 64 bit.

This is the entry where I have to create a key in case it is 64 bit platform:

```
H_KEY_LOCALMACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Sparx Systems\EAAddins\AdminAddins
```

This is the entry where I have to create a key in case it is 32 bit platform:

```
H_KEY_LOCALMACHINE\Software\Sparx Systems\EAAddins\AdminAddins
```

This is how the registry entries are defined in code:

```
<Component Id="AdminAddinsRegEntries" Guid="8777A7AB-B147-4850-9F25-65011306E9C6" >
  <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Wow6432Node\Sparx Systems\EAAddins\AdminAddins" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
     <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="AdminAddins.MyClass" />
  </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

How can I add the condition to avoid two different installers?

Comment: If your installer is running as x86, you can select the registry key as "HKEY_LOCALMACHINE\Software\Sparx Systems\EAAddins\AdminAddins" and when installing on a 64 bit system, it will be silently redirected to the Wow6432Node. So the answer should be just to make a 32 bit installer.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, Thanks, How can I make the installer run as x86?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628790/build-wix-3-6-project-targeting-x64 which tell you how to target x64 or x86, but I think the default is x86 anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make a 32 bit install package. That's all. The system, through the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx), will handle all the details of the separate 32/64 bit registry views for you.

The 32 bit package is processed by a 32 bit process when installed on a 64 bit system and is subject to registry redirection. The redirector will arrange for the key to be written in the 32 bit view of the registry.

You should not hardcode the `Wow6432Node` string. Just in case you miss that bit, let me say it again. You should not hardcode the `Wow6432Node` string.

So, to summarise:

1. Make a 32 bit package.
2. Use `Software\Sparx Systems\EAAddins\AdminAddins` as the registry key.
3. Let the redirector take care of the 32/64 bit registry view details.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How and where should I create the package you've mentioned?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking there. I was under the impression that you already have a WiX project.

Comment: Yes, I did, but as a beginner please let me know the details as much as you can, Thanks.

Comment: If you already have an x86 project, then you are already done. Nothing more to do. Install the .msi package on a 64 bit system and the registry redirector will do the rest. Are you familiar with the redirector and how it works?

Comment: No, It is the first time for me to hear about the registry redirector. How can I make the installer to run as x86?

Comment: Well, I do suggest that you read the article I linked to very carefully and make sure you understand the implications. The third paragraph of my answer is very important. As for your WiX project, it presumably already targets x86. I cannot see your WiX project file so I don't know. There have been various different ways to specify this in WiX and without knowing more details, possibly beyond the scope of this question, I can't give you detailed advice on that.

Comment: The application platform is x86. The registry entry is hardcoded to `H_KEY_LOCALMACHINE\Software\Sparx Systems\EAAddins\AdminAddins`. That's all? Is it suitable for both 32 and 64 bit platforms?

Comment: Yes, the x86 package will install fine on both 32 and 64 bit platforms.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it please.

Comment: That's a different question altogether. Unaccepting my answer to the question you asked doesn't help much. What are you hoping to achieve by doing that. It appears mean and ungracious. I cannot understand the logic behind that move. Please ask a new question about your new problem.

Comment: I thought it is related to the 64 and 32 bit issue. Please get my apologies.